# Why primitive to class type conversion destroys object values?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

Why in the below code when I set `c1 = 10` destroys all other values of variables (`a`, `b`, `c`) of the object. The statement should call the constructor and as the constructor is defined it sets the values of `a` to `10`, but when I try to access values of `b` and `c`; it is giving me garbage values.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class abc{
    private:
    // properties
    int a,b, c;
    
    public:
    
    void setdata(int x,int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    void showdata(){
        cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << "\n";
    }
    
    // constructors
    abc(){}
    
    abc(int k)
    {
        a=k;
    }
};
int main()
{
    
abc c1; // object intialization
c1.setdata(6,7); // setting values of properties
c1.showdata(); // printing values

c1 = 10; // primitive to class type conversion, constructor is being called
c1.showdata(); // why value of b and other variables is getting changed ?

return 0;

}
```

Comment: You create a new object in the line `c1 = 10;` (via an implicitly converting constructor) - obviously that new object doesn't know anything about the values of any previous object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to

```
c1 = abc(10);
```

The constructor `abc(int k)` doesn't initialize values `b` and `c`, therefore the member variables contain some random values. These random values, from the temporary `abc(10)` object, are then copied to `c1`.

---

The same is true for constructor `abc()`, here neither member variable is initialized, so they all contain "garbage" values. You will see this, when you call `showdata` right after construction

```
abc c1;
c1.showdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wrote:

```
c1 = 10;
```

On the right hand side, the **converting constructor** is used to create a **temporary** object of type `abc`.

**Next**, the **assignment operator** is used to assign that temporary object on the right hand side to the object on the left hand side.

Also, note that the converting constructor `abc(int k);` **only assign** to the data member `a` and leave the data members `b` and `c` as it is. But since you've not explicitly initialized member `b` and `c` they have **indeterminate value**. And using/accessing those values(`b` and `c`) leads to **undefined behavior**.

This is why it is advised that

> always initialize built in types in local/block scope.

To **solve** this you can use **in-class initializers** as shown below:

```
class abc{
    private:
    // USE IN-CLASS INITIALIZERS
    int a = 0,b = 0, c =0;
    
    public:
    
    void setdata(int x,int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    void showdata(){
        cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << "\n";
    }
    
    // constructors
    abc(){}
    
    abc(int k)
    {
        a=k;
    }
};
```

Also not that instead of assigning a value to the data member `a` inside the constructor body, you should use **constructor initializer list** to initialize it as shown below:

```
class abc{
    private:
    // USE IN-CLASS INITIALIZERS
    int a = 0,b = 0, c =0;
    
    public:
    
    void setdata(int x,int y)
    {
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    void showdata(){
        cout << "a = " << a << " b = " << b << "\n";
    }
    
    // constructors
    abc(){}
    //use constructor initializer list
    abc(int k): a{k}
    {
       //no need to assign to `a` here
    }
};
```

Comment: "assignment operator" No! move assignment is chosen! And var a is not initialzed but overwritten!

Comment: @Klaus First i am right in saying that assignment operator is used. Its just that i have not mentioned which assignment operator will be used(among copy assignment operator or move assignment operator). And i don't think there is any need for mentioning that here. Second, the data member `a` is assigned a value instead of intialized, i agree on this point.

Answer (score 1):

In fact `c1 = 10;` invokes 2 distinct steps:

- a temporary `abc` object is constructed from the  `abc(int k)` constructor - obviously its b and c values are not set
- that temporary is then assigned to `c1` using one of the move assignement operators which will replace all the members.

After that, the temporary is destroyed.

If you have good reasons to not overide previous values in a copy, you could provide a custom copy or move assignment operator. But beware, that will be used for every assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
c1 = 10;
```

creates a new object where only your constructor `abc(int k)` is called. Now you have a temporary object, which will be moved into the existing one `c1`. As you only overwrite your variable `a`, all others are not set explicitly.

I have no idea if it is intended behavior, that you create a temporary obejct which will be moved into an existing object. If you do not want it, you should make your constructor `explicit`.

BTW: You constructor did not initialize your variable `a` but overwrite it. For an `int` type, it doesn't matter but for other types which are not default constructible, it will not work.

You should always the constructor initializer to initialize your variables like:

```
abc(int k): a{k}{}
```